# How to prevent helm upgrade from treating string as bool?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'm running a `helm upgrade` command to install a certain chart. Of one the values I need to set is like this:

```
helm upgrade --install someService someChart `
             --set coredns.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"="true"
```

I have used this successfully with other charts but on this particular chart I'm getting the error

```
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to decode "": json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field ObjectMeta.metadata.annotations of type string
```

So it looks like helm is automatically converting that `true` into a bool. I already tried to use `="\"true\""` but that also didn't help.

Any ideas how to tell helm to not convert this to bool? (I do not have control over the helm  chart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `helm upgrade --set-string` to force Helm to interpret the value as a string.

```bash
helm upgrade --install someService someChart \
             --set-string coredns...=true
```

Note that `helm install --set` has somewhat unusual syntax and quoting rules; you're already seeing this with the need to escape periods within a value name.  You might find it clearer to write a YAML (or JSON) file of installation-specific values and pass that with a `helm install -f` option.

```yaml
coredns:
  service:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

```bash
helm upgrade --install someService someChart \
             -f local-values.yaml
```

This is a separate file from the `values.yaml` file that's part of the chart, and its values are merged with the chart's values with the local values taking precedence.

Comment: awesome, --set-string is exactly what I needed. thank you